# why cant we pass &array to function where &array[0] is possible

Tags: c++

```
void fun(int* array){}  


int main(){

int array[]={1,2,3};
fun(&array);----->(1)//error in this line
return 0;
}
```

`error: cannot convert âint (*)[3]â to âint*â for argument â1â to âvoid fun(int*â).`

if i am passing `fun(&array[0])`,its working fine.As per my understanding `&array` and `&array[0]` both yield the same address.Kindly clarify.

Comment: @Adriano: Not in C++.  It should be `int (*)[3]`.  And it is (see the error message)

Comment: @Adriano array & &array both yield the same address.I have printed the values .

Comment: Adriano, your incorrect comment is terrible. Please don't write such things unless you actually know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Adriano: Which `array`, the first or the second?

Comment: @KerrekSB: `&array` only occurs in the code once, inside `main`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I know, but Adriano's comment doesn't necessarily mean that he's referring to an `&array` in the code, I thought...

Comment: Absolutely poor and vague comment, my mistake!

Answer (score 5):

While the address of any aggregate (this means arrays and standard-layout classes) is guaranteed to be the same as the address of the first element, the types are different, and there is no implicit conversion.

---

As an example why the different type is important and useful:

```
for( int *p = array; p < (&array)[1]; ++p )
```

iterates over all elements of `array`, while

```
for( int *p = array; p < (&array[0])+1; ++p )
```

only executes once.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 if you run this:

```
#include<iostream>
template<class T>
void foo(T t) {
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   int arr[] = {1,2,3};
   foo(arr);
   foo<decltype(arr)>(arr);
   foo(&arr);
   foo(&arr[0]);
}
```

It will produce the result:

```
void foo(T) [with T = int*]
void foo(T) [with T = int [3]]
void foo(T) [with T = int (*)[3]]
void foo(T) [with T = int*]
```

Interestingly, the array collapses into a pointer by default (not sure if this is gcc behaviour or expected).  However, the second line shows that the type of `arr` is `int[3]`, and so `&arr` is a *pointer to `int[3]`* which is different than `int*`.

Answer (score 1):

They don't work because they imply different element sizes. Indexing an `int*` increases it's address by `sizeof(int)`, as it indexes into an array of `int`. Indexing an `int(*)[3]` increases it's address by `sizeof(int) * 3`, as it indexes into an array of arrays of 3 ints. Thus, even though the starting address is the same, they are very different types and imply very different pointer arithmetic. The compiler is quite correct to tell you that they are not compatible.

Comment: This is the best answer really.

Comment: This answer is slightly wrong.  That is not the reason it doesn't work.  It is an interesting fact, and might clarify the real reason (that they are different types), however, it is not the underlying reason.  Else passing the address of an array of 1 int(or any other type that is the same size as an int) would work.

Comment: That is the specific disambiguator in this case- there are others in other cases. It is the specific reason that the types are not compatible in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays naturally decays to pointers when passed around. You don't have to use the address-of operator.

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatching types.

The function expects `*int` (pointer to an int).

`array` and `&array[0]` is of that type, `*int`.

But `&array` is of type `int(*)[3]` (pointer to an array of 3 ints).

Comment: Thank you  Alex for the info

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
void fun(int* array){} // int *array is integer pointer so it can point to int not the int pointer. 

int main(){

int array[]={1,2,3};
fun(array); //remove &. now *array of pm point to array[0] i.e int.
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't compatible with `int**` either.  (What should happen if the function tries `*array = 0;`, which is perfectly legal for an `int**`?)